# How to toggle "Fn" key on HP Notebooks

Tags: hp-pavilion, minecraft, function-keys

I have been playing Minecraft a lot recently. As Minecraft player would know Function keys are very important while doing stuff there. As I play on laptop, I have to everytime combine Fn key and then the fucntion key I want to press. Is there any toggle option on HP Notebooks. Please tell

Comment: Check the Bios. That's where you normally change it.

Comment: Try `Fn`+`Esc`. That is the toggle on Dell laptops. This does depend on the motherboard and the BIOS. Check the HP site for instructions for your particular model.

Answer (score 1):

Many HP and Dell laptops have option in the BIOS to use F keys directly or via `Fn`, so check it out on next reboot. I believe you need to press `Fn`+ `F1` or `F2`  to enter BIOS right after computer powers-on. 
 Then scroll through menus for this option.

Answer (score 1):

For permanently changing the <kbd>Fn</kbd> button mode on HP Laptop Model 17 series

- enter BIOS by pressing <kbd>F10</kbd> directly after Startup
- go to main menu "Configuration"
- set Action Key mode to "Disabled"
- save and exit BIOS and re-start laptop